# ocamldep: Argument list too long

Tags: ocaml

I'm having the infamous `Argument list too long` error when running `ocamldep` with a large number of input files.

This issue only happens when using a native Windows OCaml compiler + Cygwin: in this configuration, `ARG_MAX` returns 32000, an awfully low value, which I believe is a limit imposed by Windows itself, not Cygwin.

The usual solution for this kind of error is to use `xargs`, if we can split the arguments, such as when using `ls` or `rm`, but I don't know how it could work with `ocamldep`. Since it expects all files to be given in the command line at the same time (to properly compute dependencies), and there seems to be no option to give the list of files in a file (as in `-f filelist.txt`), is there a way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` since you do not need to list all the files for `ocamldep` at once.

For example, in OCaml compiler's source code, to know the dependencies of GraphicsX11 over Graphics, you do not need to list graphcs.ml

```
$ cd otherlibs/graphics
$ ocamldep graphicsX11.ml
graphicsX11.cmo : graphics.cmi graphicsX11.cmi
graphicsX11.cmx : graphics.cmx graphicsX11.cmi
```

However, you must make dependees accessible `ocamldep`, otherwise they are ignored. Actually GraphicsX11 depends on Hashtbl too, and it is found with `-I dir` option:

```
# Seek dependencies over stdlib modules too:
$ ocamldep -I ../../stdlib/ graphicsX11.ml
graphicsX11.cmo : ../../stdlib/hashtbl.cmi graphics.cmi graphicsX11.cmi
graphicsX11.cmx : ../../stdlib/hashtbl.cmx graphics.cmx graphicsX11.cmi
```

(Personally I have never seen an OCaml project more than 32000 ml/mli files. Wow.)

Comment: It's not the number of arguments, but the total size of the expanded command line that must not exceed `ARG_MAX`. At least it seems so, because I copied the expanded command line into a file and it was slightly larger than 32 KiB (on my Linux `ARG_MAX` is actually 2MiB, with a 128 KiB buffer). 80% of that are overly long directory names repeated over and over, BTW. Not ideal, but we're still far from 32k files...